# Declare structure in C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, visualgdb

I build project with Visual Studio and compile by using GCC located in `raspberry pi` with help of VisualGDB

I have simple c file with structure:

```
struct labing
{
    lv_obj_t* panel;
    lv_obj_t* label; 
    const char* title;
    int high;
    int width;
};

void createTopPanel(lv_obj_t * screen, labing * lb)
{
...
}
```

Compiler generates error:

```
error: unknown type name ‘labing’; did you mean ‘long’?
```

Looks like compiler doesn't understand structure `labing` declaration. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Typedef the struct or always write `struct labing` for the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't understand `labing`, because there is no `labing` type, only a `struct labing` type.

Either use a `typedef` like this (which will do the `typedef` *and* the declaration of the `struct`):

```
typedef struct labing
{
    lv_obj_t* panel;
    lv_obj_t* label; 
    const char* title;
    int high;
    int width;
} labing;
```

or change

```
void createTopPanel(lv_obj_t * screen, labing * lb)
```

to

```
void createTopPanel(lv_obj_t * screen, struct labing * lb)
```

What *you* did would compile with C++, but not with C.